# Is it possible to use CSS media queries for hiding input boxes but showing their values when printing?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is it possible to use CSS media queries for hiding input boxes but showing their values when printing?

```
<input type="text" value="Print this value but not the input box."/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the input boxes transparent backgrounds and borders:

```
@media print {
    input[type="text"] {
        display: inline;
        color: #000;
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
    }
}
```